# Image Path Not Overriding

Tags: php, android, android-intent, android-activity

Problem: Activity 1 has a path to an image, activity 2 has a different path to a different image when activity 1 is sending the image file via an intent.

Code Activity 1:

```
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        imageFile = new File(outputFileUri.getPath());
    } else if (requestCode == UPLOAD_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Get the data back from the request in URI format (Path to file).
        selectedImage = data.getData();
        imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
    menuIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    menuIntent.putExtra("username", username);
    menuIntent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
    menuIntent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
    menuIntent.putExtra("imageFile", imageFile);
    Log.d("ACTIVITY1 image", imageFile.getPath());//THIS LOG BELOW!!
    try{
        startActivity(menuIntent);
        finish();
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        menuIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(menuIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Reason for try catch on the Intent is this activity is being used for a different usage apart from this one.
Code Activity 2:

```
...
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        username = extras.getString("username");
        latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
        longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
        if(extras.get("imageFile") != null){
            File imageFile = (File) extras.get("imageFile");
            Log.d("ACTIVITY2 image", imageFile.getPath());//THIS LOG BELOW!!
            toastContext = getApplicationContext();
            params = new ArrayList();
            params.add("upload");
            params.add(username);
            params.add(imageFile);
            uploadImage = new UserFunctions(this);
            uploadImage.execute(params);
        }
    }
}
```

There is an ASyncTask that sends the files via POST to a server and JSON is returned to form a notification and updates it according to the response. No problems there.
Activity 2 loads if the user is signed in, if not, activity 2 gets called later on, when the user signs in.
The issue occurs when activity 2 loads activity 1 via a buttonListener, then activity 1 either takes a photo or has a file chosen. When activity 1 has decided, it immediately loads activity 2 again, passing the new imageFile in the intent. When activity 2 loads, it sends the request off to the server.
Logs returned are:
First time the image is send via POST:

```
 DEBUG/ACTIVITY1 image(15559): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130215_193022.jpg
```

Then passed to activity 2 via intent...

```
 DEBUG/ACTIVITY2 image(15559): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130215_193022.jpg
```

Second time, after picking a different image or taking a new photo:

```
 DEBUG/ACTIVITY1 image(15559): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130214_212205.jpg
```

Then passed to activity 2 via intent...

```
 DEBUG/ACTIVITY2 image(15559): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130215_193022.jpg
```

If there is a request for the ASyncTask/onPostExecute, I'll post it!

Thanks!

Edit: Added Android Manifest for clarification of Activities:

```
<activity android:name=".ACTIVITY1" android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".ACTIVITY2"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:parentActivityName=".ACTIVITY1"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:taskAffinity=""
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ACTIVITY1"/>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man I feel bad...

After Activity 2 starts the ASyncTask:

```
 uploadImage = new UserFunctions(this);
 uploadImage.execute(params);
```

the activity needs to end.
Adding

```
 finish();
```

fixed it.